# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo Error

Tags: android

I wanna ask something about android programming..
I create a class that return display from rss xml file to android but i get some error

> 04-08 14:37:19.162: E/AndroidRuntime(381):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.xmlreader/com.example.xmlreader.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

**Code:**

```
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXMLFromURL(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElem(xml); // getting DOM element

(*) NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
```

the error in line 38 or line i was give (*) this mark...
pleas help me...

Answer (score 0):

If the nullpointer is coming up on below line (with *):

```
 (*) NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM); //i reckon the nullpointer is coming up on the doc object...
```

Then I reckon to check whether the xml which is being retrieved from the getXMLFromURL method
is correct?:

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXMLFromURL(URL); // getting XML   (Is this correctly retreived?
Document doc = parser.getDomElem(xml); // getting DOM element  (This is returning null)
```

For more help share your XMLParser class

Comment: Your answer sounds more like a comment, cause you're not giving a way to solve the issue.

Comment: "Then I reckon to check whether the xml which is being retrieved from the getXMLFromURL method is correct?:" (The answer is xml is not correct)
Would it make sense to put all of the above explanation with correct code indentation in a comment?

Comment: It would make sense to shorten the description so that it would fit into a comment, just because answering a question means suggesting a clear way of solving a problem, and not making assumptions about the code and stating that you don't have enough information to give a more precise solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use a **Thread** or **AsyncTask** to perform the "Networking Operations". Otherwise you will get NetworkOnMainThreadException. [read this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)
2. Add permission to AndroidManifest.xml.

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

   An example using a Thread

   ```
    menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    final XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);

           handler.post(new Runnable() { //create an object of Handler class in onCreate() - (android.os.Handler)
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
                   nl =doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                   //other code inside onCreate() - for loop
               }
           });
      }
   }
   th.start();

   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems, R.layout.list_item,
               new String[]{KEY_NAME, KEY_COST, KEY_DESCRIPTION}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.cost, R.id.description});

   setListAdapter(adapter);
   ```